# Delete a message sent by telegram bot in PHP

Tags: php, bots, telegram

I created a bot in php to make two strangers talk.The function that I would like to implement is the possibility of having a user delete a message that has already been sent and therefore that it is no longer visible to the other user. In particular, the user replies to the message to be deleted and this is also deleted from the other user.

I tried to use [deleteMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage) manually putting as message_id the id of the message sent by the bot to the other user but obviously it doesn't work.If I reply to the message to be deleted actually in my chat it is deleted but the other user does not because the message_id is not the same.
[image: the idea of ​​operation].

The question is how to get the message id in the other chat and then delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Messages from bot to user1 and user2 are not connected to each other on telegram side.
To solve your problem you can save message_id (1) and message_id (2) in your database and find message_id (2) by message_id (1).

When user1 reply "/delete" on any message in his chat your bot will receive new message with "reply_to_message" section from where you can get message_id (1) to delete and second message_id (2) you will find in your DB.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. the problem is that I manually got the message id and using deleteMessage trying both userid1 and userid2 and also botid but it says the message doesn't exist.

Comment: botid???  in order to delete message you have to use message_id and chat_id

Comment: And that's the problem. Which chat_id should I use? I tried both with the ids of the two users and the ID of the bot, but with none the message is deleted.

Comment: I tried them on a single one.

Comment: read limitations here https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage

Comment: I used your method for the db, thank you. The function returned an error because I had missed the letter i in chat_id.